# C++ : automatic const?

Tags: c++, const-correctness

When I compile this code:

```
class DecoratedString
{
private:
    std::string m_String;
public:
     // ... constructs, destructors, etc
     std::string& ToString() const
     {
         return m_String;
     }
}
```

I get the following error from g++: `invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::string&" from expression of type 'const std::string'`.

**Why is m_String being treated as const?  Shouldn't the compiler simply create a reference here?**

EDIT:

Further, **what should I do to get this function to act as a conversion to a string that will work in most cases?**  I made the function const, as it doesn't modify the internal string... maybe I just need to make it return a copy...

EDIT:  Okay... making it return a copy worked.

Comment: You can, of course, have the function return a `const std::string&`.

Comment: @James McNellis - And the const would mean that... the reference is constant, or that the data in the reference is constant?  Sorry, just read Herb Sutter's paper on const-correctness yesterday and am attempting to learn how to use const more effectively in my code.

Comment: @sheepsimulator:  That would make it a reference to a const object, just like a `const std::string*` would be a pointer to a const object.  Since a reference cannot be rebound (i.e., once you initialize a reference to refer to some object, it can never refer to any other object), the notion of a "constant reference" (i.e., a `std::string& const`) is nonsensical.

Comment: @James McNellis - good point.  I'll do that instead.

Comment: Since it's nonsensical, however, the notion "const reference" is unambiguous, and refers to "const T&". (this notion is existing practice in the Standard Library documentation). So don't be afraid to say "const reference" when you mean a reference that refers to a const object - it's not wrong.

Comment: +1 to what @Johannes says; I didn't meant to imply otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`m_String` is treated as const because it is accessed as

```
this->m_String
```

and `this` is const because the member function, `ToString()` is const-qualified.

Answer (score 3):

`m_String` is `const` at that point because you've chosen to declare the **method** as `const` (which of course makes all data instance members const, too) -- if you need to bypass that for that specific data member, you could choose to explicitly make it `mutable`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the method is const (the `const` in `std::string& ToString() const`). Const method see `this` as a `const` object, and its memebers as `const` objects, too.

Answer (score 1):

Because you access `m_String` through a constant `this` (the method is `const`).